# get script to run again if user input is yes in java

Tags: java

I need help making it so that the entire script will loop from the beginning if the user types y at the end and the script ends if the user types n at the end. Thanks for any help.

```
package test123;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test321 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;  
        int c;
        String playAgain;

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     n = scanner.nextInt();

      if ( n < 0 )
         System.out.println("Number cant be a negative.");
      else
      {
         int x=n*(n-1)*(n-2);

         System.out.println("Factorial= "+x);

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n):");
         playAgain = scanner.nextLine();

          }while (!playAgain.equals("y"));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need help" is not a question.

Comment: change `while (!playAgain.equals("y"))` to `while (playAgain.equals("y"))`

Comment: your code is wrong, pay attention to the { }

Comment: how am i supposed to put the { }?

Comment: read your code and check your if else block and the do while ... the while is closed before the else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package test123;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test321 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int n = 1;  
    int c;
    String playAgain;

     do {

          System.out.println("Enter a number");
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          n = scanner.nextInt();

  if ( n < 0 )
     System.out.println("Number cant be a negative.");
  else
  {
     int x=n*(n-1)*(n-2);

     System.out.println("Factorial= "+x);

    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n):");
     playAgain = scanner.nextLine();
   } // end else
 } // end do
 while (playAgain.equals("y"));

}// end main
```

} // end class

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
while (!playAgain.equals("y"));
```

to

```
while (!playAgain.equals("n"));
```